# I got error "hostname: Name or service not known" when checking IP of hostname

Tags: ubuntu, hostname, ip-address

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 on my company's cloud service
(my instance has elastic IP). 
I want to check out the IP address of my instance I'm running
by command line, but it didn't work.

```
root@ubuntu14-graphite:~# hostname
ubuntu14-graphite
root@ubuntu14-graphite:~# hostname -i
hostname: Name or service not known
```

I don't understand the reason why.

I tried to ping to ubuntu14-graphite but it said:

```
unknown host ubuntu14-graphite.
```

Does that mean my host doesn't even exist?

I have another server (not cloud instance but physical server). 
In this server I installed CentOS 6.7. 
I checked the hostname's IP and it worked
even though there was nothing special in `/etc/hosts`.

Here's the output of `cat /etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1         ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0     ip6-localnet
ff00::0     ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1     ip6-allnodes
ff02::2     ip6-allrouters
ff02::3     ip6-allhosts
```

Answer (score 18):

It means that "the system" (I'm using that term in a broad,
general, ambiguous sense) doesn't know that the name `ubuntu14-graphite`
corresponds to your host and its IP address. 
(The fact that is is your host's ***name*** isn't enough to make this happen.) 
This almost surely means that you don't have a line for `ubuntu14-graphite`
in your `/etc/hosts` file<sup>†</sup>,
and that it's not in your naming service (e.g., DNS or NIS). 
Consequently, a way to fix it
is to add `ubuntu14-graphite` (and its IP address) to your `/etc/hosts`. 
If you're using a more sophisticated (distributed) naming system
such as DNS or NIS (or maybe ActiveDirectory?),
the ultimate solution is to add your host to that service.
_____________
† ... and I see from your post of your hosts file that this is the case.

There is some debate over the question of
what IP address you should associate with your host name. 
Everyone agrees that it should be an address that "works" for your host;
i.e., commands like `ping A.B.C.D` should succeed. 
Some people recommend using a loopback address. 
Loopback addresses are always of the form 127*.B.C.D*;
common values are 127.0.0.1 and 127.0.1.1. 
Other people recommend using a LAN address,
which might look like 192.168*.C.D* (but it can be almost anything) —
but you should not put a dynamically assigned address into your hosts file
(and, if you're using DHCP with DNS,
then the dynamically assigned address(es)
should be entered into your DNS records automatically). 
Use commands like `ifconfig` and `hostname -I`
to see what addresses are in use.

Comment: Thanks your your answer. I edited my question because i noticed one more case related to my CentOS server which doesn't have anything but 127.0.0.1 localhost but i still be able to check my host's IP.

Comment: Well, maybe the name and address of the CentOS server are entered into the DNS system (or whatever name service is in use).

Comment: In the CentOS system, the bind and bind-utils was not installed. So i'm really confused.

Comment: @TheOne Ubuntu treats `hostname` differently that RH based systems..put `127.0.1.1  ubuntu14-graphite` in the `/etc/hosts` file and check..note, its `127.0.1.1`, not `127.0.0.1` (which you can preserver anyway just for localhost, as `127.0.0.0/8` is loopback block you can use any address although some systems have predefined restricted addresses)

Comment: @heemayl So by putting 127.0.1.1 ubuntu14-graphite on /etc/hosts then check the IP i  didn't get the right IP. That doesn't make sense,right?

Answer (score 1):

The actual way to check a machine's IP address is by using the `ifconfig` command.

Note that depending on the actual cloud setup, the server instance may not be aware of the public IP and only know a VLAN IP.  For details on this, you need to refer to your provider's documentation.

Comment: Nope; `ip a s`. See https://serverfault.com/q/458628/89813 - ifconfig is deprecated on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Add the `myhostname` entry to the `hosts` service in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`.

In other words, change this line in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`:

```
hosts:      files dns
```

to this:

```
hosts:      files dns myhostname
```

Where usually hostnames are resolved using the `/etc/hosts` file and dns, the hostname of the system can also be resolved by telling the Name Service Switch to do so (as this configuration change will do).

This would explain why you didn't see anything special about the `/etc/hosts` file on the system that you could resolve the local hostname.

More information on the `myhostname` flag is [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/nss-myhostname.8.html).

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it depends on version of hostname command (net-tools package).

See: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=319981

- example on "openSuse Leap 42.3":

```
    # hostname -V
    net-tools 1.60
    hostname 1.100 (2001-04-14)

    # hostname -i
    hostname: Name or service not known
```

- on Lubuntu 17.10

```
  $ hostname -V
  hostname 3.18
```

`hostname -i` - gives me information about IPv6 and IPv4

Comment: That bug report is about `hostname -s`, not `hostname -i`. This isn’t related to versions of `hostname`, it’s related to whether the hostname given by `hostname` is resolvable.

Answer (score -3):

Go to etc/hosts.save check your hostname there. And then edit `/etc/hosts`
to write there your hostname and the hostname in `hosts.save`. Also check the IP address. Example:

```
127.0.0.1    ubuntu   
127.0.1.1    ubuntu.ubuntu-domain    ubuntu
```

Comment: Setting a localhost IP in `/etc/hosts` will not give them the actual IP address.  I also fail to see why you're also looking at `/etc/hosts.save` which is a technicality and very irrelevant.